# Tool tip on Struts2 select tag options

Tags: struts2

I have select tag, options inside this is bigger one.not able to see in the drop down itself. How to see that in Tooltip?how to configure it?

```
<s:select cssClass="drop" list="lstEntities"
                            cssStyle="width:500px"  
                            id="select_statement" listKey="statementId"
                            listValue="conditionStatement">
                            </s:select>
```

Please help on this.

Answer (score 0):

Add title attribute to this tag with the tooltip you want.

```
<s:select cssClass="drop" list="lstEntities"
                            cssStyle="width:500px"  
                            id="select_statement" listKey="statementId"
                            listValue="conditionStatement"
                            title="toolTip text">
                            </s:select>
```

Comment: I want for every options. if i select first option it show the info..if i select select option it should show anothe info.

Comment: In that case you need to this using JavaScript... Use Javascript to set Title attribute depending upon the value

Comment: Is the way to override the Struts2 select tag class method which is constructing select and option tags?